# Configuring Multiple HttpVerbs using EndPoint Routing in ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am getting an exception when I have multiple action methods with same verb i.e. POST, in the Account controller of my newly setup WebApi project using default template in Visual Studio. Here's the info about VS:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.3.10
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.3.10+29519.87
```

Here is the exception that I get:

```
InvalidOperationException: The method 'post' on path '/api/Account' is registered multiple times.
```

Here is my the default routing setup in the Startup file:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

I have also tried the following but it didn't help.

```
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api",
            pattern: "{controller}/{id?}");
```

and

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

I have read about the end point routing at the official docs as well, but I am not able to figure out what am I missing. You help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass template name i.e. `[HttpPost("my-other-route")]`.

Comment: Is using route attribute necessary for all action methods in ASP.Net Core WebAPI?

Comment: @SuperCoder the `Route` attribute means all HTTP verbs are accepted, and it's typically (in my experience, at least) used on the controller. The `Http(Verb)` attributes are used on controller actions. If you have multiple actions on the same controller with the same HTTP verb, their route templates have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `Route` attribute for the `Controller` as shown

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{ ... }
```

You could call the `PostStudent` action with the request route like `https://localhost:44346/api/students/postStudent` and call the `PostStudentList` action with the request route like `https://localhost:44346/api/students/postStudentList`.